# Is $A^*A$ a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Given $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose, I want to know if the matrix $A^* A$ is a positive definite. Recall that a matrix $B$ is positive define if and only if, $$v^*Bv >0$$ for all $v\in \mathbb{C}^{n} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Apply the definition you provided and think of the definition of the Euclidean norm

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on wheher $A$ is singular. If $A$ is non-singular, then $Av$ will be non-zero for non-zero $v$ and $$v^*A^*Av=(Av)*(Av)>0$$.If $A$ is singular, hen $Av=0$for some non-zero $v$, so $v^*A^*Av=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I proved Hadamard inequality for a positive definite matrix and wanted to extend the inequality for a general matrix using $A^*A$. But i guess i will have to prove the inequality for a positive semi-definite matrix.